# Can multiple email clients use the same POP3 account?

Tags: windows, email, microsoft-outlook, pop3, windows-phone

I have a webmail account with POP3 enabled.  I use Microsoft Outlook 2007 with this account, and it works well.

However, I'm curious as to what happens when **I set up the same POP3 account elsewhere** (say a Windows Phone 7), how does that work?  Will the mail in Outlook and the Windows Phone sync or will I have issues or what?  Can only one be set up at a time?

Comment: If you leave out the POP part, the answer is: you can't with POP, use IMAP instead. Makes the whole question look more logical ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a POP3 mailbox is accessed and emptied on a certain device, another device won't be able to receive the received mail as well. However, most mail clients offer an option to "Leave message copy on the server". This will allow other devices to access the same mail also.

For sync purposes however, you might want to check if your provider offers IMAP as a service.

Comment: Such as: IMAP can also sync your Sent Items and other folders.